# Default syntax highlighting as in "emacs -Q"

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, colors

I want to use the syntax highlighting that you get when running `emacs -Q`.  If I run `emacs -q`, or run Emacs with no `~/.emacs` file existent, or not load any custom theme, I get a dark-backgrounded color theme.  I also tried altering my init file, but to no avail. Disabling a custom theme also leads to the dark theme aforementioned.

How can I get the font-lock colors default in `emacs -Q`?

Comment: The difference between -q and -Q is that site-start files are loaded. Start by checking if there is something in the system setup that cause your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Initial Options` tells us:

```
‘-Q’
‘--quick’
     Start emacs with minimum customizations.  This is similar to using
     ‘-q’, ‘--no-site-file’, ‘--no-site-lisp’, and ‘--no-splash’
     together.  This also stops Emacs from processing X resources by
     setting ‘inhibit-x-resources’ to ‘t’ (*note Resources::).
```

Hence the difference you're seeing between using `-q` and `-Q` is going to be on account of one (or more) of:

- `--no-site-file`
- `--no-site-lisp`
- setting `inhibit-x-resources` to `t`

You can check the first two by running: `emacs -q --no-site-file --no-site-lisp`

```
‘--no-site-file’
     Do not load ‘site-start.el’ (*note Init File::).  The ‘-Q’ option
     does this too, but other options like ‘-q’ do not.

‘--no-site-lisp’
     Do not include the ‘site-lisp’ directories in ‘load-path’ (*note
     Init File::).  The ‘-Q’ option does this too.
```

I would be more suspicious of the X resources, though.  If it's that, you *may* just be able to add `(setq inhibit-x-resources t)` in your init file, but my tests for that were not successful, so YMMV.

See also:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Resources`
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ResourceFiles

Comment: This is it. I checked '--no-site-file' and '--no-site-lisp' options separately, but I never really suspected Xresources because setting the variable didn't work, so I thought Xresources wasn't really relevant. Also some of the colors were different from those set in Xresources.Thanks.